# How can I make the search results editable?

Tags: lightning, search

In Lightning, if I go to Contacts->My Contacts, I can edit the columns of any returned value.

But if I do a search, I cannot edit the columns.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to edit the values of the records from Search results, that is not possible.  You can only edit the values by going to the record page.

If you are looking to changing the columns, here is the way.

Go to. Setup --> Object Manager --> Contact --> Search Layouts.

Click on Edit of Search Results.

There you can change the columns

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't edit records in List view. Salesforce doesn't provide support for this.